# MVC4 load data into partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

my main (MyProfile) view contains links that when user clicks on the link the partial view loads in the div with existing data from DB that can be updated by the user.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Update 1", "Update1", new { email = @ViewBag.Email }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divCurrentView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }) 

@Ajax.ActionLink("Update 2", "Update2", new { email = @ViewBag.Email }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divCurrentView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }) 

 <div id="divCurrentView">
 </div>
```

Partial Views: example:

_Update1:

```
@model ViewModels.Update1
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)                               
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) 
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
 <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

_Update2:

```
 @model ViewModels.Update2
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)                               
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Website)
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
 }
```

In the Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Update1(string email)
    { 
        var model = populate the viewmodel
        return PartialView("_Update1",model);
    }
public PartialViewResult Update2(string email)
    { 
        var model = populate the viewmodel
        return PartialView("_Update2",model);
    }
```

It doesnt mean the user will click on all the links when accessing the main view.

I want to get feedback if my way is correct OR should I load all the data once when the user gets to MyProfile View and store the data in the session and when each partial view gets loaded data gets loaded from the session?
This would avoid calling the db every time partilaview gets loaded or is there a better approach?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use Cache as suggested but the problem the data is store globally. If multiple users login and try to view/update the data, the data is identical for all of them Am I missing something?

This is what tried:

```
  public PartialViewResult Update1(string email)
    {
        var cc = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("cinfo");
        Update1VM model = null;
        if (cc == null)
        {
            model = populate the viewmodel
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("cinfo", model);
        }
        else
        {
            model = (Update1VM)cc;
        }

        return PartialView("_Update1", model);
    }
```

Comment: Depends on how much data we are talking about storing in session. If it isn't a lot, sure that works. If not then you probably want to not store it in session.

Comment: how much data is alot? I have about 20 fields.

Comment: will it always stay as 20 fields? Will that ever change? Remember someday you won't be there and someone else will need to deal with what you have created. Personally I have never been a huge fan of storing stuff in session simply because the round trip to the db is not desired. py3rstr's repsonse below in serving up data when needed as opposed to always loading everything.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Html.ActionLink` in way you use is good solution. It makes controller simple and reuseble. You can easily add and remove views without changes in controller. It is easy to put them in diffrent view. 
Generally it's more flexible solution.

If you afraid of calling the db every time you can always use some caching, but in your example it will query db only when user really need it and click it.

If you put this in one view it will be more complicated, more messy and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks. Scenario user clicks on update1 link and then on update2 link (back and forth) x 10 times without modifying the data. To avoid calling the db additional times I assume I should use caching? or what if the user does update one partilaview's data do I store it in the cache? can you please provide a sample example of how i would do it?

Comment: Take a look at [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.100).aspX) You can cache data from db and remove when it is updated see [example](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/using-the-system-web-cache-object-into-your-mvc3-project). You can also use `Html.Action` helper to render all children action in single request. And some jquery tab plugin to switch between forms. In this case user can click as many times as he want don't creating db queris and action still be separated.

Comment: When you say render all children action in a single request. Do you mean on my main view (myprofile) capture all fields into 1 viewmodel and then have tabs for each partialview and load data from the one viewmodel? have all partialviews use the same viewmodel?

Comment: I mean render this two action on myprofil using [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703641(v=vs.118).aspx) helper. ex. `@Html.RenderAction("Update1", new { email = ViewBag.Email })`

Comment: I tried to use Cache as suggested but the problem the data is store globally, I have update my question, can you advice what am I missing? thanks for your help

Comment: Insted of string `"cinfo"` use `email` variable. Or somw combination of string and variable like: `HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("cinfo" + email)`

Comment: So all the cache will be store on the server. Is it better to store the object on the client? I am thinking in the future if the company will have many users updating there profile accounts it will affect the resources? this is all new to me, sorry for asking so much. Is it possible to make cache store on users machine?